# Why does Windows 7 mouse freeze after resuming from sleep?

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse, freeze, sleep

A similar question previously posted at Super User is [Why does my Windows 7 computer freeze after waking up from Sleep?](https://superuser.com/q/10502/81992), but none of the previous answers intially appeared to solve my problem or were the same as my initial answer.

On one of my Windows 7 machines, the mouse would be permanently frozen after the machine woke up from sleep. The mouse would not move though the cursor was displayed. I had no option but to power down the machine and reboot.

This happened often, though not always. If the machine had only been sleeping a few minutes, I could wake it up and use the mouse. If the machine had been sleeping an hour or so, then the mouse would be permanently frozen when the machine woke up.

Comment: you should've posted the answer under the answers section, not mixed with the question. Why other question are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've posted my own answer below also, and added a link to the previous similar question.

Comment: thanks, I've further edited he question so that the question looks like a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initially thought the problem might be caused by the Windows 7 Advanced Power Setting "USB Selective suspend setting" being Enabled, which is apparently the default for Windows 7. This allows Windows to disable USB devices that are infrequently used, so it seemed this might be happening in my case, with a machine that frequently sleeps. This setting can be changed by navigating to:

1. Control Panel;
2. Hardware and Sound;
3. Power Options;
4. Change Plan Settings (for any power plan);
5. Change advanced power settings;
6. USB settings and set "USB selective suspend setting" to Disabled.

What I've found through experiment is that my problem is solved by using a newer mouse. Both the new mouse and the old mouse are supposedly identical, and were purchased as the Microsoft Optical Intellimouse. The freeze problem happens repeatably with my older mouse, whether USB selective suspend is enabled or disabled. The freeze problem does not happen with the newer mouse, whether USB selective suspend is enabled or disabled.

In all my tests, both mice have been used directly connected to the PC via the same USB connector. No mousepad was used -- both mice function ok on my desktop without a mousepad. There are no options in the BIOS for my PC to change USB settings for mice. The PC is relatively new, an HP Pavilion Slimline purchased about a year ago.

Remarkably, this answer (replacing with a new, apparently identical mouse) is the same as one of the answers given on the similar question.

Comment: I have an Intellimouse too. So you say it's a hardware issue on the mouse? that's odd. It didn't happen for me on Windows 7, but started occuring on Windows 8 : sometimes, either when starting the OS or waking it up, the mouse barely moves (almost frozen), letting me only to click the buttons, and when I disconnect it and re-connect it again, it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Something happened to me but in Windows initialization. I fixed the problem just with a mousepad :)

I think the local that I draged my mouse is not the best for laser signal of my Chinese mouse :) (the cursor "magically" moved when I was not using it).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your mouse device (or USB host it is attached to) is not initialized properly after sleep.
You can try to resolve this (you will need a keyboard which still works):

- open Device Manager (press <kbd>Win</kbd>, start typing `devmgr` in Windows menu, device manager will show up, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start). You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between your browser with these instructions and the Device Manager window.
- find your mouse device under "Mice and other pointing devices" category, and select it (using <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move focus into device tree view, and then <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> to select "Mice and other pointing devices",  <kbd>→</kbd> to open the category, <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> to select the device).
- switch into "Devices by connection" view (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to open "View" menu, arrows or <kbd>V</kbd> to select "Devices by connection", <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- enable "Show hidden devices" (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to open "View" menu, then <kbd>w</kbd> to select "Show hidden devices")
- now select parent USB device to which your mouse is attached (using arrows)
- Disable the parent device (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to open "Action" menu, arrows or <kbd>E</kbd> to select "Disable device", left arrow to select "Yes" in the popup confirmation dialog, and <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Enable the parent device again (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to open "Action" menu, arrows or <kbd>E</kbd> to select "Enable device")

This will hopefully power cycle the misbehaving device and fix it. If it doesn't, you can try to disable/enable the device which is even higher up in the hierarchy, just make sure you don't have your keyboard connected to the same branch!